# Deployer How can I build my JS application (Yarn)?

Tags: php-deployer

I'm using Deployer and I think I've got everything working, but I now need to CD into my js folder and execute `yarn build`. This has proven quite tricky since I can't seem to get the path right with deployer. For example my task is this;

```
task('frontend:build', '
  cd /js;
  yarn;
  yarn build;
');
```

But I constantly get this error that it doesn't exist?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try,

```
task('frontend:build', function() {
  cd('/js');
  run('yarn');
  run('yarn build');
});
```

your task will run on your host

EDIT: I've made a typo